# "The specified type was not recognized" when desearalizing a XML file using auto-generated schema

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I want to explain my entire process so far, as I am new to working with XML files and hopefully someone can point out what step I messed up at. If you want to just see my question I will ask it concisely at the bottom.

I am trying to import a XML file that was generated via the accounting software Peachtree. Here is a stripped shortened version of the XML file called `ITEM.xml`

```
<PAW_Items xmlns:paw="urn:schemas-peachtree-com/paw8.02-datatypes"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-datatypes">
    <PAW_Item xsi:type="paw:item">
        <ID xsi:type="paw:id">00002</ID>
        <Description>Example1</Description>
        <Class>1</Class>
        <isInactive>TRUE</isInactive>
        <Subject_to_Commission>FALSE</Subject_to_Commission>
        <Description_for_Sales>Example1</Description_for_Sales>
        <Sales_Prices>
            <Sales_Price_Info Key="1">
                <Sales_Price>5.22000</Sales_Price>
                <Sales_Price_Calc>NC</Sales_Price_Calc>
                <Sales_Price_Rounding>0</Sales_Price_Rounding>
                <Sales_Price_Rounding_Cent>0.00000</Sales_Price_Rounding_Cent>
            </Sales_Price_Info>
            <Sales_Price_Info Key="2">
                <Sales_Price>0.00000</Sales_Price>
                <Sales_Price_Calc>NC</Sales_Price_Calc>
                <Sales_Price_Rounding>0</Sales_Price_Rounding>
                <Sales_Price_Rounding_Cent>0.00000</Sales_Price_Rounding_Cent>
            </Sales_Price_Info>
        </Sales_Prices>
        <Tax_Type>0</Tax_Type>
        <Last_Unit_Cost>5.22000</Last_Unit_Cost>
        <Costing_Method>1</Costing_Method>
        <GL_Sales_Account xsi:type="paw:id">40000</GL_Sales_Account>
        <GL_Inventory_Account xsi:type="paw:id">12000</GL_Inventory_Account>
        <GL_COGSSalary_Acct xsi:type="paw:id">50000</GL_COGSSalary_Acct>
        <Type>SA</Type>
        <Stocking_UM>BTL</Stocking_UM>
        <Weight>0.00000</Weight>
        <Minimum_Stock>0.00000</Minimum_Stock>
        <Reorder_Quantity>0.00000</Reorder_Quantity>
        <Vendor_ID xsi:type="paw:id">B&amp;L</Vendor_ID>
        <Substock_Primary_Attributes>
        </Substock_Primary_Attributes>
        <Substock_Secondary_Attributes>
        </Substock_Secondary_Attributes>
        <QuantityOnSO>0.00000</QuantityOnSO>
        <QuantityOnPO>0.00000</QuantityOnPO>
        <QuantityOnHand>0.00000</QuantityOnHand>
        <IsTaxable>TRUE</IsTaxable>
        <Print_Components>FALSE</Print_Components>
        <Number_of_Components>0</Number_of_Components>
        <Components>
            <Component>
                <Effective_Date xsi:type="paw:date"/>
                <Component_Number>0</Component_Number>
                <Qty_Needed>0.00000</Qty_Needed>
            </Component>
        </Components>
    </PAW_Item>
    <PAW_Item xsi:type="paw:item">
        <ID xsi:type="paw:id">0001</ID>
        <Description>Example2</Description>
        <Class>1</Class>
        <isInactive>TRUE</isInactive>
        <Subject_to_Commission>FALSE</Subject_to_Commission>
        <Description_for_Sales>Example2</Description_for_Sales>
        <Sales_Prices>
            <Sales_Price_Info Key="1">
                <Sales_Price>4.39000</Sales_Price>
                <Sales_Price_Calc>NC</Sales_Price_Calc>
                <Sales_Price_Rounding>0</Sales_Price_Rounding>
                <Sales_Price_Rounding_Cent>0.00000</Sales_Price_Rounding_Cent>
            </Sales_Price_Info>
            <Sales_Price_Info Key="2">
                <Sales_Price>0.00000</Sales_Price>
                <Sales_Price_Calc>NC</Sales_Price_Calc>
                <Sales_Price_Rounding>0</Sales_Price_Rounding>
                <Sales_Price_Rounding_Cent>0.00000</Sales_Price_Rounding_Cent>
            </Sales_Price_Info>
        </Sales_Prices>
        <Tax_Type>0</Tax_Type>
        <Last_Unit_Cost>4.39000</Last_Unit_Cost>
        <Costing_Method>1</Costing_Method>
        <GL_Sales_Account xsi:type="paw:id">40000</GL_Sales_Account>
        <GL_Inventory_Account xsi:type="paw:id">12000</GL_Inventory_Account>
        <GL_COGSSalary_Acct xsi:type="paw:id">50000</GL_COGSSalary_Acct>
        <Type>SA</Type>
        <Stocking_UM>EA</Stocking_UM>
        <Weight>0.00000</Weight>
        <Minimum_Stock>0.00000</Minimum_Stock>
        <Reorder_Quantity>0.00000</Reorder_Quantity>
        <Substock_Primary_Attributes>
        </Substock_Primary_Attributes>
        <Substock_Secondary_Attributes>
        </Substock_Secondary_Attributes>
        <QuantityOnSO>0.00000</QuantityOnSO>
        <QuantityOnPO>0.00000</QuantityOnPO>
        <QuantityOnHand>0.00000</QuantityOnHand>
        <IsTaxable>TRUE</IsTaxable>
        <Print_Components>FALSE</Print_Components>
        <Number_of_Components>0</Number_of_Components>
        <Components>
            <Component>
                <Effective_Date xsi:type="paw:date"/>
                <Component_Number>0</Component_Number>
                <Qty_Needed>0.00000</Qty_Needed>
            </Component>
        </Components>
    </PAW_Item>
</PAW_Items>
```

The first thing I did was create a XSD file based off of the XML file using the [XML Schema Definition Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28VS.80%29.aspx) with the following command

```
xsd ITEM.xml
```

That generated two XSD files `ITEM.xsd` and `ITEM_app1.xsd`

ITEM.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="PAW_Items" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:app1="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance" schemaLocation="ITEM_app1.xsd" />
  <xs:element name="PAW_Items" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="PAW_Item">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              <xs:element name="Class" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
              <xs:element name="isInactive" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="3" />
              <xs:element name="Subject_to_Commission" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="4" />
              <xs:element name="Description_for_Sales" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="5" />
              <xs:element name="Tax_Type" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="6" />
              <xs:element name="Last_Unit_Cost" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="7" />
              <xs:element name="Costing_Method" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="8" />
              <xs:element name="Type" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="9" />
              <xs:element name="Stocking_UM" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="10" />
              <xs:element name="Weight" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="11" />
              <xs:element name="Minimum_Stock" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="12" />
              <xs:element name="Reorder_Quantity" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="13" />
              <xs:element name="Substock_Primary_Attributes" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="14" />
              <xs:element name="Substock_Secondary_Attributes" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="15" />
              <xs:element name="QuantityOnSO" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="16" />
              <xs:element name="QuantityOnPO" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="17" />
              <xs:element name="QuantityOnHand" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="18" />
              <xs:element name="IsTaxable" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="19" />
              <xs:element name="Print_Components" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="20" />
              <xs:element name="Number_of_Components" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="21" />
              <xs:element name="ID" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent msdata:ColumnName="ID_Text" msdata:Ordinal="1">
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute ref="app1:type" />
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Sales_Prices" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Sales_Price_Info" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="Sales_Price" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="0" />
                          <xs:element name="Sales_Price_Calc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                          <xs:element name="Sales_Price_Rounding" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
                          <xs:element name="Sales_Price_Rounding_Cent" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="3" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="Key" type="xs:string" />
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="GL_Sales_Account" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent msdata:ColumnName="GL_Sales_Account_Text" msdata:Ordinal="1">
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute ref="app1:type" />
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="GL_Inventory_Account" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent msdata:ColumnName="GL_Inventory_Account_Text" msdata:Ordinal="1">
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute ref="app1:type" />
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="GL_COGSSalary_Acct" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent msdata:ColumnName="GL_COGSSalary_Acct_Text" msdata:Ordinal="1">
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute ref="app1:type" />
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Vendor_ID" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent msdata:ColumnName="Vendor_ID_Text" msdata:Ordinal="1">
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute ref="app1:type" />
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Components" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Component" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="Component_Number" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="Qty_Needed" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                          <xs:element name="Effective_Date" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:attribute ref="app1:type" />
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute ref="app1:type" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

ITEM_app1.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mstns="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:app1="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xs:attribute name="type" msdata:Prefix="xsi" type="xs:string" />
</xs:schema>
```

I then tried to just use the command `xsd ITEM.xsd /c` but that did not work.

```
E:\test>xsd ITEM.xsd /c
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.17929]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Schema validation warning: The 'http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance:type' attribute is not declared. Line 113, position 14.
Schema validation warning: The 'http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance:type' attribute is not declared. Line 35, position 24.
Schema validation warning: The 'http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance:type' attribute is not declared. Line 61, position 24.
Schema validation warning: The 'http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance:type' attribute is not declared. Line 70, position 24.
Schema validation warning: The 'http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance:type' attribute is not declared. Line 79, position 24.
Schema validation warning: The 'http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance:type' attribute is not declared. Line 88, position 24.
Schema validation warning: The 'http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance:type' attribute is not declared. Line 103, position 32.

Warning: Schema could not be validated. Class generation may fail or may produce incorrect results.

Error: Error generating classes for schema 'ITEM'.
  - The attribute type is missing.

If you would like more help, please type "xsd /?".
```

Using `ITEM_app1.xsd` and trying to list both files neither work, after searching for a bit I found you could list multiple files if you used the `/parameters` argument. So I created a parameters file with the following

```
<xsd xmlns='http://microsoft.com/dotnet/tools/xsd/'>
<generateClasses language='CS' namespace='Peachtree'>
    <schema>ITEM.xsd</schema>
    <schema>ITEM_app1.xsd</schema>
</generateClasses>
</xsd>
```

And that successfully created `ITEM_ITEM_app1.cs` (you can get a [copy of the code at pastebin](http://pastebin.com/5xe61MqC) because posting it here makes this question go over the max post size limit)

I created this simple program to test it

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Peachtree;

namespace Sandbox_Console
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var file = File.OpenText(@"E:\test\ITEM.xml"))
            {

                var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PAW_Items)); //Line 16
                var result = (PAW_Items) ser.Deserialize(file);

                Debugger.Break();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I first tried to run it I got this exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'Peachtree.PAW_ItemsPAW_ItemSales_PricesSales_Price_Info[]' to 'Peachtree.PAW_ItemsPAW_ItemSales_PricesSales_Price_Info'
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'Peachtree.PAW_ItemsPAW_ItemComponentsComponent[]' to 'Peachtree.PAW_ItemsPAW_ItemComponentsComponent'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Peachtree.PAW_ItemsPAW_ItemSales_PricesSales_Price_Info' to 'Peachtree.PAW_ItemsPAW_ItemSales_PricesSales_Price_Info[]'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Peachtree.PAW_ItemsPAW_ItemComponentsComponent' to 'Peachtree.PAW_ItemsPAW_ItemComponentsComponent[]'

  Source=System.Xml
  StackTrace:
       at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(Assembly parent, String ns, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters xmlParameters, Evidence evidence)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence, XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Assembly assembly, Hashtable assemblies)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(XmlMapping xmlMapping, Type type, String defaultNamespace)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type)
       at Sandbox_Console.Program.Main(String[] args) in e:\Code\Sandbox Console\Program.cs:line 16
  InnerException:
```

However I found that this is a [known issue with xsd.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2486643/en-us) when you have complex types in complex types. I just changed the two classes that had `[][]` to `[]` in the generated file and that solved the issue.

---

## My problem:

When I attempt to deserialize the file I get the following exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=There is an error in XML document (4, 3).
  Source=System.Xml
  StackTrace:
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)
       at Sandbox_Console.Program.Main(String[] args) in e:\Code\Sandbox Console\Program.cs:line 16
  InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=The specified type was not recognized: name='item', namespace='urn:schemas-peachtree-com/paw8.02-datatypes', at <PAW_Item xmlns=''>.
       Source=Microsoft.GeneratedCode
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderPAW_Items.Read10_PAW_ItemsPAW_Item(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderPAW_Items.Read11_PAW_Items(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
            at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderPAW_Items.Read12_PAW_Items()
       InnerException:
```

It appears that it is blowing up on `<PAW_Item xsi:type="paw:item">` and it does not know what to do with the `xsi:type="paw:item"` part.

If I try to add `PAW_ItemsPAW_Item` to the known types by changing my code to

```
var types = new[] {typeof (PAW_ItemsPAW_Item)}; //Line 15
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PAW_Items), types);
var result = (PAW_Items) ser.Deserialize(file);
```

I get the following error on the `new XmlSerializer(...)` line

```
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Cannot include anonymous type 'Peachtree.PAW_ItemsPAW_Item'.
  Source=System.Xml
  StackTrace:
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.IncludeType(Type type, RecursionLimiter limiter)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, XmlAttributeOverrides overrides, Type[] extraTypes, XmlRootAttribute root, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)
       at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, Type[] extraTypes)
       at Sandbox_Console.Program.Main(String[] args) in e:\Code\Sandbox Console\Program.cs:line 15
  InnerException:
```

What step did I miss that is causing this to happen?

Comment: this could be because var types = new[] {typeof (PAW_ItemsPAW_Item)}; You haven't declared type to include paw:item

Comment: @HappyLee The variable `types` is not used, it was part of some earlier testing when I did `var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PAW_Items), types);` but that did not fix the problem. I just forgot to remove that initialization line after I took it out.

Comment: @HappyLee I have updated my question to include the exception I get when I do include the type.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the first error you get which is generating the code from ITEM.xsd. xsd.exe reports that the type attribute is missing for all attributes

```
<xs:attribute ref="app1:type" />
```

within the complex types. These attributes were generated due to the xsi:type attributes in your ITEM.xml file.
I guess you want xsd.exe to generate the schema so that the specified type (paw:id, paw:item) is used for those attributes. I don't know if this works with xsd.exe, you may need to use additional command-line options on xsd.exe or use a different tool like try xsd2code for example.

Comment: Can you show an example of what I I would need to edit in the xsd file or a example of how to use xsd2code to get this to work?

Comment: I tried xsd2code but I ended up getting a `InvalidOperationException` "*There was an error reflecting type 'ITEM.PAW_Items'*", the inner most exceptions where "*There was an error reflecting type 'ITEM.PAW_ItemsPAW_Item'*" with "*Inconsistent sequencing: if used on one of the class's members, the 'Order' property is required on all particle-like members, please explicitly set 'Order' using XmlElement, XmlAnyElement or XmlArray custom attribute on class member 'Description'.*"

Comment: In your ITEM.xml, remove the xsi:type="..." attributes and try again generating a schema. Those attributes try to engorve a certain type but since the XML is generated by your software, such constraints are not required. You may want to post-process the XML for this...

Comment: it's kinda moot now, MSDataSetGenerator works with it as-is, I will still give you the +1 for the good advice.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out if you use visual studio's (2012) designer it works fine.

I just added the `.xsd` file to my project and it used the tool `MSDataSetGenerator` and it created a DataSet that deserialized the file fine. A DataSet will work fine for my uses.